# How to override native control methods (OnViewAdded/OnViewRemoved)?

Tags: maui

In Xamarin, you could override native methods on a control by creating a custom renderer and using `override`:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyPage), typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
public class MyPageRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    public override void OnViewAdded(View child)
    {
        //Custom code when page is navigated to here
    }
}
```

In MAUI, renderers have been removed and replaced with handlers. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/renderer-to-handler?view=net-maui-8.0) spends a lot of time explaining how to port the `OnElementChanged` method, but doesn't explain how to port any other overridden methods.

So, how can I port (for example) `OnViewAdded`/`OnViewRemoved`?

Comment: It's still possible to use Xamarin.Forms custom renderers in .NET MAUI apps. For more information, please check:  [Reuse custom renderers in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers?view=net-maui-8.0).

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT No, it's not. According to the page you linked, only a handful of renderers are actually supported.  If I attempt to use any other ones, the "Renderer" class is marked as deprecated, and at runtime I get `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`

Comment: What have you tried? And how can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post more code snippets about this?

Comment: If you mean "reproduce the issue with custom renderers", I posted a (highly related) bug report [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21030). But even if that's fixed, that doesn't answer my question - if Renderers are deprecated, what's the "correct" way to implement the equivalent functionality?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT There were a (large) number of bugs in Xamarin that could only be fixed using custom renderers.  Some of these required overriding methods other than `OnElementChanged`; two examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78108513/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78135747/), but there are others. Most of these bugs still exist in Maui. Since handlers only seem to replace `OnElementChanged`, I can't find workarounds for other bugs. So I'm asking if there's a general solution.

Comment: For your problem, you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose).