# How to remove native padding from picker/switch?

Tags: maui

The `Switch`, `Picker`, and probably others have no writable `Margin` or `Padding` properties, and have a built-in margin (or padding?) that I can't seem to get rid of.

Xamarin had the same problem. [This blog post](https://alexdunn.org/2017/07/24/xamarin-tip-borderless-picker/) provides a solution, but unfortunately that no longer works with MAUI:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PickerHandler.Mapper.PrependToMapping("PickerHandler", (handler, view) =>
{
    // This line crashes because handler.PlatformView.LayoutParameters is null prior to the control being laid out
    var layoutParams = new MarginLayoutParams(handler.PlatformView.LayoutParameters);
    layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    handler.PlatformView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
    handler.PlatformView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
});
```

I tried having the code instead run on `handler.PlatformView.LayoutChange`, but that has no effect (possibly because the control is already laid out at that point??).  I also tried using [reusing Xamarin custom renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers?view=net-maui-8.0) but the `PickerRenderer` no longer works, it crashes the app.

So **how can I remove the unwanted padding/margin**?

Comment: I've created a related feature request [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21016)

Comment: Might want to check my library out it might help you with this https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After literally 15 hours working on this issue, I've come up with a massive hack that seems to mostly work.

If you set `Margin="0,-10"` on the component, the surrounding controls will be laid out as though the native margin didn't exist.

This works perfectly for `Switch`. However, for `Picker` the margin is still displayed, but it now overlays everything else.

[image: Microsoft y u so dumb]

Incredibly, setting the `ZIndex` does not work. The only thing I could get to work was setting `BackgroundColor="Transparent"` so that the margin can't be seen.  If you actually want a background, you can probably finagle something with a surrounding `Box` or something.

The only issue I've seen is that when the `Picker` is focused, the red underline highlight can overlap with the controls below the Picker. I haven't found a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the process of trying to convert Renderers to Handlers and these are the steps I have so far. I'm going to use the code in the blog you attached as the example ...

Create a class in the common code for your custom control:

```
namespace TestApp.Controls
{
    public class BorderlessPicker : Picker
    {
    }
}
```

Create a partial class in the common code for your custom handler, then copy this file into your Platform specific folders:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;

namespace TestApp.Handlers
{
    public partial class BorderlessPickerHandler
    {
    }
}
```

In the platform specific files, determine the object this handler will be derived from.  In this example `PickerHandler` was valid for both iOS and Android, in code I did for Entry the `EntryHandler` was only available in iOS, I had to use `ViewHandler<UnmodifiedEntry, EditText>` in Android.

Note - do not change the namespace in the platform specific files, it needs to match the namespace in the common file.

```
 public partial class BorderlessPickerHandler : PickerHandler
```

In the platform specific files, override `CreatePlatformView` and add any code that was in `OnElementChanged`.  The code will need to be modified a bit, but this is a good starting point. My Android specific file now contains:

```
public partial class BorderlessPickerHandler : PickerHandler
{
    protected override MauiPicker CreatePlatformView()
    {
        var view = base.CreatePlatformView();
        view.Background = null;
        var layoutParams = new MarginLayoutParams(view.Width, view.Height);
        layoutParams.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        view.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
        view.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and the iOS specific now contains:

```
public partial class BorderlessPickerHandler : PickerHandler
{
    protected override MauiPicker CreatePlatformView()
    {
        var view = base.CreatePlatformView();
        view.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
        view.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
        return view;
    }
}
```

Edit - I found if I skipped this step the picker works as desired.  I'm leaving this in hoping someone will comment on it -

*In the common code, define the `PropertyMapper` and `CommandMapper` and pass them in to the base constructor. This should bring in any mappers that were defined for the base object.  This is also where custom mappers can be defined.
Note - this can only be done in common code if both partial classes used the same base type.  If they don't, then this needs to be done in the platform specific code.
public partial class BorderlessPickerHandler
{
public static IPropertyMapper<BorderlessPicker, BorderlessPickerHandler> PropertyMapper =
new PropertyMapper<BorderlessPicker, BorderlessPickerHandler>(new PropertyMapper<IPicker, IPickerHandler>(ViewHandler.ViewMapper));
public static CommandMapper<BorderlessPicker, BorderlessPickerHandler> BorderlessCommandMapper = new CommandMapper<BorderlessPicker, BorderlessPickerHandler>(CommandMapper);

```
    public BorderlessPickerHandler() : base(PropertyMapper, BorderlessCommandMapper)
    {
    }
}*
```

Edit - pick it back up here -

Finally in your MauiProgram.cs, add the code to the `builder` to associate the handler with the control:

```
.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
{
    handlers.AddHandler<BorderlessPicker, BorderlessPickerHandler>();
})
```

Maui also makes use of Styles for standard controls and by default these styles are not applied to derived types. To get the styles to apply, open \resources\Styles\Styles.xaml and add `ApplyToDerivedTypes="True"`.  There is a minimum height and minimum width set for the default picker if the app was created from the MAUI template.

```
<Style TargetType="Picker" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
```

In testing this I'm not getting perfect results - the picker title is not appearing, I've found looking at the base code can help with issues like this.  However the control does expand on Android if the item picked is wider than the control as it does in the standard picker indicating that the base mappers are being applied to the derived object .

Comment: _"In testing this I'm not getting perfect results - the picker title is not appearing"_ - I posted [this bug](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21030) a few days ago.  Even with a _completely empty_ renderer, that issue occurs.  So I don't think your code is doing what you think it's doing. For me, the custom renderer code wasn't even executing. You can get the code to run using `UseMauiCompatibility` + `AddCompatibilityRenderer`, but even then I wasn't able to get the native padding removed.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft you needed to use AddCompatibilityRenderer because you were using a custom renderer, the code above uses a custom handler, they are two different things.  Did you look at the styles?

Answer (score 0):

probably DIY is the solution if you are perfectionist and want things in certain way. i have referred this person code as he calls under the question comment ["freakycontrols" by Ali](https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls) , however you may need to install this with nugget.

```
Install-Package Maui.FreakyControls
```

if ur not third party fan or not allowed to use many packages, you can always borrow smaller snippets and integrate with project declaration file. i apologize cant give any guarentees however, you can try in project and infform me.

```xml
<!-- CustomPicker.xaml -->
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Controls.CustomPicker">
    <Border Margin="{Binding Margin, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomPicker}}}"
            Padding="{Binding Padding, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomPicker}}}">
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomPicker}}}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomPicker}}}" />
    </Border>
</ContentView>
```

```cs
// CustomPicker.xaml.cs
namespace MyApp.Controls
{
    public partial class CustomPicker : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CustomPicker));

        public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SelectedItem), typeof(object), typeof(CustomPicker));

        public static readonly BindableProperty MarginProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Margin), typeof(Thickness), typeof(CustomPicker), default(Thickness));

        public static readonly BindableProperty PaddingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Padding), typeof(Thickness), typeof(CustomPicker), default(Thickness));

        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        public object SelectedItem
        {
            get => GetValue(SelectedItemProperty);
            set => SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
        }

        public Thickness Margin
        {
            get => (Thickness)GetValue(MarginProperty);
            set => SetValue(MarginProperty, value);
        }

        public Thickness Padding
        {
            get => (Thickness)GetValue(PaddingProperty);
            set => SetValue(PaddingProperty, value);
        }

        public CustomPicker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

#### and for the switch : here is copy paste

```xml
<!-- ModernSwitch.xaml -->
<freaky:FreakySwitchView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                         xmlns:freaky="clr-namespace:Maui.FreakyControls;assembly=Maui.FreakyControls"
                         x:Class="MyApp.Controls.ModernSwitch"
                         IsToggled="{Binding IsToggled, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ModernSwitch}}}"
                         OnColor="{Binding OnColor, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ModernSwitch}}}"
                         OffColor="{Binding OffColor, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ModernSwitch}}}"
                         ThumbColor="{Binding ThumbColor, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ModernSwitch}}}"
                         Margin="{Binding Margin, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ModernSwitch}}}">
    <freaky:FreakySwitchView.Behaviors>
        <freaky:SwitchBehavior />
    </freaky:FreakySwitchView.Behaviors>
</freaky:FreakySwitchView>
```

```cs
// ModernSwitch.xaml.cs
namespace MyApp.Controls
{
    public partial class ModernSwitch : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsToggledProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsToggled), typeof(bool), typeof(ModernSwitch), false);

        public static readonly BindableProperty OnColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OnColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ModernSwitch), Colors.Green);

        public static readonly BindableProperty OffColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(OffColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ModernSwitch), Colors.Gray);

        public static readonly BindableProperty ThumbColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ThumbColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ModernSwitch), Colors.White);

        public static readonly BindableProperty MarginProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Margin), typeof(Thickness), typeof(ModernSwitch), default(Thickness));

        public bool IsToggled
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsToggledProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsToggledProperty, value);
        }

        public Color OnColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(OnColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(OnColorProperty, value);
        }

        public Color OffColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(OffColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(OffColorProperty, value);
        }

        public Color ThumbColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(ThumbColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(ThumbColorProperty, value);
        }

        public Thickness Margin
        {
            get => (Thickness)GetValue(MarginProperty);
            set => SetValue(MarginProperty, value);
        }

        public ModernSwitch()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

To use this `ModernSwitch` control

```xml
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls"
```

And then use like this:

```xml
<controls:ModernSwitch IsToggled="{Binding SwitchValue}" OnColor="Green" OffColor="Gray" ThumbColor="White" Margin="0" />
```