# How to implement a full-screen overlay?

Tags: maui

I would like to draw a semi-transparent overlay over most (but not all) of the screen.

[image: Screenshot]
*screenshot of the feature working in Xamarin*

The most obvious solution is to use an `AbsoluteLayout` + `GraphicsView`. However, this doesn't work because Xamarin/Maui don't allow `AbsoluteLayout` to draw things over the `NavigationPage` navigation bar.

---

The solution in Xamarin was to write a custom `NavigationPageRenderer` and override `DispatchDraw`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(MyNavigationPageRenderer))]
public class MyNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
{
    ...
    protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas screenCanvas)
    {
        base.DispatchDraw(screenCanvas);
        // Custom drawing code here - screenCanvas can draw on the entire screen
    }
}
```

In Maui, you have two choices:

1. **Use a compatibility renderer** via `.AddCompatibilityRenderer`.  However, as far as I can tell, these are just completely broken.  [Even a completely empty one crashes the app](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21116).
2. **Use a [Maui handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0)**.  However, these seem to be *significantly* less powerful than renderers. There is no way to override methods on native controls; there is no draw event to hook into on either the native or platform control; and there is no draw command in the `CommandMapper`.  So I can't figure out any way to draw things.

So, **how can this feature be implemented in Maui?**

Comment: Looks like a popup. There are some packages you can use for this, e.g. [MAUI Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) or [Mopups](https://github.com/LuckyDucko/Mopups).

Comment: @Julian I'm aware of those, and none of them allows for drawing on the overlay _(notice the hole in the screenshot)_. I haven't yet looked to see if the underlying code can be adapted for my usecase.

Comment: lol so, digging further, it seems [Mopups hasn't been able to get full-screen drawing to work using Handlers either](https://github.com/LuckyDucko/Mopups/issues/106)

Comment: You can try this https://redth.codes/popups-with-net-maui-no-plugin-nuget-needed

Comment: @AlessandroCaliaro The code on that page does not work with a NavigationPage, same as the example I already gave

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft how a person with 84.6k reputation, uses "does not work" to describe code behavior? Using NavigationPage, a modal popup draws over page content, toolbar and navigation bar (for android, for ios you need a little "convincing" to do). And even if it does not, you cannot do anything with it anyway. Another important thing: Navigation Page is used to shuffle stack of ContentPages. Nothing more, nothing less. And it is a Page. A Page arranges its children in area. And this area does not match the Window, quite obviously I must say. This code may change without notice.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft about handlers and overriding methods of native controls. The handler is not a control. You are not extending the control, you are mapping properties and commands. If you want to draw over page, using Alessandro's suggestion is the best, if you do not want to interact with the interface bellow the draw. If you want to experiment with combining them, the display_name's answer will be more suitable, just change "Rectangle" to "Rect". It does compile.

Comment: @H.A.H. Please read again. "It does not work, **same as the example I already gave**". It does not draw over the NavigationPage navigation bar.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft In what OS does not draw over it? This modal popup can draw over pretty much anything in android. If we talk about IOS, there is a way to force it.

Answer (score 1):

> Use a Maui handler. However, these seem to be significantly less powerful than renderers. There is no way to override methods on native controls; there is no draw event to hook into on either the native or platform control; and there is no draw command in the CommandMapper. So I can't figure out any way to draw things.

Handlers are the link between Cross-Platform views and native views.
They are not used to override methods of controls, because they are not controls themselves.

MAUI `GraphicsView` is virtual view. The link between the virtual and native view, is the `GraphicsViewHandler`. The native control behind it is `PlatformTouchGraphicsView`. And it extends the specific platform graphics view.

The way this control works, in Android case, is that it overrides the View's `Draw` method, that accepts a `Canvas` object as argument. And inside it, the `IDrawable` takes that canvas for its own Draw method.

The handler for the virtual view, only maps two properties - the Drawable, and the FlowDirection. And one command - Invalidate.

Let's say that the default implementation of GraphicsView does not suit us, and we want to write our very own:

1. GraphicsView, being virtual cross-platform view, stays as it is.
2. We implement our own CustomGraphicsView class and we override:

   ```
   public override void Draw(Canvas androidCanvas)
   ```
3. We implement our own CustomTouchGraphicsView : CustomGraphicsView, changing touch event, hover, moves etc (All this work that the MAUI team have done), and most importantly the `Connect` and `Disconnect` methods.
4. We implement our own public class CustomGraphicsViewHandler : ViewHandler<IGraphicsView, CustomTouchGraphicsView>, ICustomGraphicsViewHandler

(Those are implemented as partials, but we can just put all this code in one class)

5. We add our handler in the MauiProgram.cs

   ```
   .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
               {
                   handlers.AddHandler(typeof(GraphicsView), typeof(CustomGraphicsViewHandler));
               });
   ```

Now instead of the MAUI team's code, when we add GraphicsView to the XAML, our code will be used instead. (As long as we use Android, because we implemented the native interpretation of GraphicsView for ANDROID platform only... Now we have to write few hundred lines for the other platforms as well.) This means we have full control over every single line of drawing code. Mapped to cross platform control. This is the power of handlers.

Anyway, now to the root of your problem:

When we implement our own View (understand as base for controls in android), we have overridden the Draw method. That canvas we are using, even if position at 0,0, we will not be drawing over the screen. There is a visual hierarchy. And our view is far far far down.

Meaning your problem is not that handlers cannot override methods. It was the visual elements hierarchy all along.

You can target the Activity (I see in your comments that according to you it was the "only" working solution). But for this you need to write a lot of platform specific code, and platform specific services.

You still need to get a platform view, to add to the activity root view. You can run this code, in your page, to see how it will convert the default GraphicsView, to graphics view of the specific platform:

```
GraphicsView graphicsView = new GraphicsView();       
graphicsView.Drawable = new GraphicsDrawable();
var platformView = graphicsView.ToHandler(this.Handler.MauiContext).PlatformView;
```

I still recommend you to use `Navigation.PushModalAsync()`, and save yourself all this non-sense. I am being able to draw over everything with it. And if it does not draw over something, it will not respond to clicks anyway. Very simple, 10 seconds solution that draws over full screen.

Edit: Semi-transparent overlay with transparent circle in it:

1. Add new ContentPage to your project.
2. Set `BackgroundColor="Transparent"` to the ContentPage itself.
3. Make a grid with your controls:

   ```
   <Grid>
       <Path 
           Opacity="0.7"
           Fill="Black">
           <Path.Data>
               <GeometryGroup>
                   <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="150"
                            RadiusY="150"
                            Center="180,200" />
                   <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1000,1000" />
               </GeometryGroup>
           </Path.Data>
       </Path>
   </Grid>
   ```
4. Call your popup with: `Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PopupPage(), false);`

Comment: +1 thank you for the explanation. Can you expand on your `PushModalAsync()` suggestion?  I'm not sure what you mean by _"I am being able to draw over everything with it"_. Is there a way to use that to push a `GraphicsView` to the root of the view hierarchy?  I'll emphasize that I'm not just looking to show a modal, I want to actually draw on the semi-transparent overlay (see the screenshot above, where there's a fully-transparent circular "hole" in the overlay). Is that possible with `PushModalAsync()`?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft of course you can. See the Edit, give it a try.

Comment: The drawing method is just an example. You can do it with background, image view, etc...  Geometries are my personal preference. Also, this "false", means non-animated pop. You may want it animated in your project. So try both ways.

Comment: I tried to get the `PushModalAsync` suggestion to work, but there seems to be a bug with how Maui calculates the page's size. With an `AbsoluteLayout`, it's able to cover the navigation bar, but it won't take the size of the navigation bar into account when calculating its own size, meaning it never covers up the _bottom_ 10% or so of the screen!  Also it doesn't honor transparency, so a black box with 50% alpha is just pitch black.

Comment: I got the rectangle transparency to work using `BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent` on the ContentView itself, and the incorrect sizing fixed by [disabling the Android action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78197219/how-to-remove-extra-title-bar-in-android-app). So now the `PushModalAsync` method correctly works with no platform-specific code (on Android at least).  Thank you!

Comment: Tip: to format code inside a list item, double-indent it (eight prefix spaces instead of four).

Comment: @halfer double thanks. For the edit and the tip.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to use a combination of a Grid layout, an AbsoluteLayout, and a BoxView to create the semi-transparent overlay.

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace MauiApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var overlayLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
            var overlay = new BoxView { Color = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) }; // Semi-transparent black overlay

            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(overlay, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(overlay, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));

            overlayLayout.Children.Add(overlay);

            var contentGrid = new Grid();
            contentGrid.Children.Add(/* Your content here */);

            // Add your overlayLayout and contentGrid to the main layout
            Content = new Grid
            {
                Children = { overlayLayout, contentGrid }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work (or even compile). As mentioned, I'm using `NavigationPage`. It's not possible to make the `NavigationPage` a child of `overlayLayout` because it's a page.  If I instead make the `overlayLayout` a child of the `NavigationPage`, it's not possible to draw over the navigation bar. Also (as already mentioned) custom renderers don't seem to work correctly anymore in Maui.