# How to remove extra title bar in Android app?

Tags: maui

When I run my app in the Android emulator, I see a title bar I can't get rid of.

[image: Titlebar]

I'm not using `Shell` or `NavigationPage` (in this screenshot)

I've tried:

- `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);`
- `Shell.SetNavBarIsVisible(this, false);`
- `Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"` in the XAML
- Changing every color in `Resources/styles/Styles.xaml` to try to identify where this bar is coming from.  It didn't change colors.
- Running `windowInsetsController.Hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.NavigationBars());` in `MainActivity`

Does anyone know how to get rid of this bar?

Comment: Could you please show the code in the xaml adnd the app.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently that was the Android "action bar".

To disable it, open `Platforms/Android/Resources/values/styles.xml` *(note that this is different from the `Styles.xaml` file mentioned in the question)* and change the parent style to `Maui.MainTheme.NoActionBar`:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Maui.MainTheme.NoActionBar">
  ...
</style>
```

Based on [the code](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Platform/Android/Resources/values/styles.xml), the setting that probably actually fixes this is

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

---

I have no idea why the action bar was completely blank; or why changing the action bar colors didn't change it; or why the `NavigationPage` uses a completely separate bar; or why it shows up by default.  Welcome to Maui.

Comment: But the MainActivity's default style(Maui.SplashTheme)  implements the Maui.MainTheme.NoActionBar.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT The default for me was `MainTheme.Base` which [is equivalent](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Platform/Android/Resources/values/styles.xml#L43) to `Maui.MainTheme`.  Possibly because this was upgraded from a Xamarin project. But that bar did not exist in Xamarin.